# AWS Fleet Management vs Dynamic Scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

What is difference between AWS EC2 Fleet Management and Dynamic Scaling?

Fleet Management will do health checks and keeps your fleet at desired computing capacity. Dynamic Scaling will automatically increase or decrease compute capacity based on load or other metrics.

Both of these seems pretty much the same. What is main difference between them?
Can you please explain with some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a post about that and you can find it here: [Dynamic scaling VS Fleet management scaling](https://dev.to/victorcosta/dynamic-scaling-vs-fleet-management-scaling-2e1l)

Fleet management
Used for:

Replacing unhealthy instances;
Distributing instances among availability-zones to maximize resilience; E.g: You're running instances in us-east, so auto-scaling can provision instances in the following AZs: us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, and us-east-1e;

Dynamic scaling
Used for:

Scaling based on cloudWatch alarm metrics or a metric type (more on that later) when a threshold is met or different measures should be taken depending on the breach of a cloudWatch alarm threshold.

Types of Dynamic scaling:

- Simple scaling: Scales based on a single cloudwatch alarm metric, and apply the measures you define;
- Step scaling: Scales based on different levels of cloud watch alarm metrics, and apply the actions you define;
- Target tracking scaling: Scales based on a metric type, but delegates the action to be taken to AWS;

Which one to use?

That's not the right question to ask. Actually you'll be using Fleet Management out-of-the-box, with the possibility of configuring Dynamic Scaling to take some custom actions;